# Upgraded from PHP 7 to 7.2, now microtime returns string instead of float

Tags: php

Is there a way to update `microtime()` so that, by default instead of `microtime(true)`, it returns a float instead of a string?

Comment: I thought string return was default in 7.0 as well

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue -- `microtime()` has always returned string and `microtime(true)` has always returned float.

Comment: It's always returned a string by default.

Comment: The output has always been a string. https://3v4l.org/PTjtN Do you have some unusual code that would show otherwise?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem...

Comment: When I run this: var_dump(is_string(microtime(true))); it returns false

Comment: You could write your own wrapper around `microtime` so that you call `microseconds()` (as an example), which you define to return `microtime(true)`. Aside from that, though...

Comment: Odds are that you've had code that would coerce the original microtime values to floats. If you want to avoid passing in a boolean, consider wrapping `microtime()` in a different function, e.g. `function customMicroTime() { return microtime(true); }`.

Comment: Assuming the only change was the newer PHP version, I'm curious to see what's going on in your code that made it look like that default changed.

Comment: Change a function's default? Nah...you will need to make a function microtime2 which would return microtime(float)

Comment: For some reason, my previous code still parsed the string to a float. It doesnt do that anymore. I just updated all uses of microtime to use microtime(true) so its compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. [Per the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) the only way to get a float back is to pass `true` as the argument. I don't see that has changed in any way (there's no RFCs for it and Internals *hates* breaking backwards compatability)

```
//Returns a float
var_dump(microtime(true));
```

Comment: It looks like that parameter's been in there since 5.0.0 (according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_microtime.asp), so take that as you will)